# Audio not play when Side Switch active

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I use this code to play audio.

```
 NSString *soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mp3",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"sound"];
 NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
 _player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
 _player.numberOfLoops = 1000;
 [_player play];
```

Audio not play when Side Switch active. How to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried on real iPad or simulator?

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov sound doesn’t work when iPad Side Switch is active. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Make sure your mp3 is added in xcode***

Use below code to make it working

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *soundPath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];

    NSError *error = nil;
    self.theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:&error];
}

- (IBAction) audioAction {
    [self.theAudio play];
}
```

---

### Edit 1

To fix sound issue when Switch is active, add below in plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

[image]

Comment: sound doesn’t work when iPad Side Switch is active. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
#import #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@interface MainLevelView : UIViewController<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
{
AVAudioPlayer *player;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/marimba_music.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
 NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
 player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];
 player.delegate = self;
 [player play];
}
```